# named path not being recognized in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am using Rails 3.1.0 and Rspec 2.12.2. I want to have an action that we post to via jQuery to:

```
/path/api/save-reply
```

I have the following spec:

```
describe 'test adding new mb post' do
  it 'shall add a new mb post' do
    post :save_reply, mb_detail: 'here is my detail', timestamp_id: 123, parent_id: 50, depth: 0
  end
end
```

with the following named route:

routes.rb

```
post '/api/save-reply' => 'api_mb#save_mb_reply', :as => :save_reply, :defaults => { :format => 'json' }
```

And get the following error:

```
1) ApiMbController test adding new mb post shall add a new mb post
   Failure/Error: post :save_reply, mb_detail: 'here is my detail', timestamp_id: 123, parent_id: 50, depth: 0
   AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
     The action 'save_reply' could not be found for ApiMbController
   # ./spec/controllers/api_mb_controller_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Shouldn't the spec be calling the correct path 'save_mb_reply' rather than trying 'save_reply'? What am I doing wrong?

If I run:

```
Mon Jan 07$ bundle exec rake routes | grep save_reply
                      save_reply POST   /arc/v1/api/save-reply(.:format)                                                 {:format=>"json", :controller=>"api_mb", :action=>"save_mb_reply"}
Mon Jan 07$
```

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller specs don't use routing for determing what to call - they just call the method you specify.

Comment: thx - this look correct. The only reason I'm using controller rather than request specs is to handle cookies. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: i think you can still spec cookie stuff in a request spec.